# Text based dispachment and processment

Tags: c#, protocols

I implemented a text based protocol that is able to process any message that follows the following format

```
<2 character Messsage Code>(\<2 character parameter><variable length value>)*
//in Regex format:
"(?<message>.{2})(\\(?<parameter>[^\\]{2,}))*"
```

In other words all messages contain 2 Letter message code and a variable number of parameters, each parameter with a 2 letter identifier and an arbitrary value.

So in it's general form the Message has the following representation

```
public class Message
{
    public Message(string messageCode)
    {
        MessageCode = messageCode;
    }

    public string MessageCode { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters { get; set; }
    public string Raw { get; internal set; }
}
```

The dispatcher receives said message and should deliver it to the most appropriate Processor. Each processor is able to handle one and only one Message code.

However I wanted my Processor would be able to Navigate through `Parameters` in a more typed fashion, like so:

```
public class EchoMessage : Message
{
    public EchoMessage() : base("EC") { }

    [Parameter(Name = "RB")]
    public string ReplyBack{ get; set; }
}
```

So this echo message can be represented by the string `EC\RBHello World`. Obviously there are other messages that will have Properties of other types, such as `int`, `bool`, `Enum`, or others.

My design goal was to build the necessary infracture so it would be easy to add new Messages, and their respective processors. Consider for instance the `EchoProcessor`

```
internal class EchoProcessor : MessageProcessor<EchoMessage>
{
    public override ProcessResult Process(EchoMessage message)
    {
        return Ok(message);
    }
}
```

---

**TL;DR**

Hopefully by now you have enough context to review the following code.

This code was completely sanitized by using tools like `StyleCop` and `Resharper`. (The only reason you are not going to find xml documentation is because I omitted them for brevity)

They are configured according to the conventions I follow, so there shouldn't much for you to comment on that end.

On the other hand feedback on `MessageProcessor` would be much appreciated.

Interfaces

```
public interface IProcessor<in TMessage> : IProcessor
where TMessage : Message
{
    ProcessResult Process(TMessage message);
}

public interface IProcessor
{
    string Name { get; }

    ProcessResult Process(Message message);
}

public interface IParser
{
    Message Parse(string message);
}

public interface IDispatcher
{
    ProcessResult Dispatch(string Message);
}
```

Implementations

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{" + nameof(Raw) + "}", Name = "{Message}")]
public class Message
{
    public Message(string messageCode)
    {
        MessageCode = messageCode;
    }

    public string MessageCode { get; private set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters { get; set; }

    public string Raw { get; internal set; }

    public Message MapTo()
    {
        var sample = ReflectionUtils.GetSubclassesOfType<Message>()
            .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Equals(this));
        var properties = sample.GetType().GetTypeInfo()
            .DeclaredProperties
            .Select(p =>
            {
                var attribute = p.GetCustomAttribute<ParameterAttribute>();
                var value = Parameters.ContainsKey(attribute.Name)
                    ? Parameters[attribute.Name]
                    : null;
                return new
                {
                    Property = p,
                    Value = value
                };
            })
            .Where(p => p.Value != null)
            .ToArray();
        var type = TypeAccessor.Create(sample.GetType());
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.Property.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
            {
                type[sample, property.Property.Name] = true;
            }
            else
            {
                type[sample, property.Property.Name] =
                   property.Value.ConvertToType(property.Property.PropertyType);
            }
        }
        sample.Parameters = Parameters;
        sample.Raw = Raw;
        return sample;
    }

    public void Validate() { }

    // ReSharper disable NonReadonlyMemberInGetHashCode
    // Those properties are assigned only in the constructor
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return MessageCode.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Message;
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return other.MessageCode == MessageCode;
    }
}

public abstract class MessageProcessor : IProcessor
{
    internal static readonly IProcessor Instance = new MessageProcessor<DummyMessage>();
    private readonly Dictionary<Message, IProcessor> _processors = 
        new Dictionary<Message, IProcessor>();

    private readonly Message _accept;

    protected MessageProcessor(Type type)
    {
        if (GetType() == typeof(MessageProcessor<DummyMessage>))
        {
            _accept = new Message(string.Empty);
            DiscoverAndRegisterProcessors();
            return;
        }

        _accept = (Message)Activator.CreateInstance(type, true);
        var msg = string.Join(" ", "Processor for message", _accept.MessageCode,
            "started");
        Trace.WriteLine(msg, "Info");
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return GetType().Name; }
    }

    public abstract ProcessResult Process(Message message);

    internal abstract ProcessResult ProcessImpl(Message message);

    protected IProcessor FindProcessor(Message message)
    {
        if (!_processors.ContainsKey(message))
        {
            return null;
        }
        return _processors[message];
    }

    private void DiscoverAndRegisterProcessors()
    {
        var subclasses = ReflectionUtils.GetSubclassesOfType<MessageProcessor>();
        foreach (var processor in subclasses)
        {
            RegisterProcessor(processor);
        }
    }

    private void RegisterProcessor(MessageProcessor processor)
    {
        _processors.Add(processor._accept, processor);
    }

    // The class is instantiated via reflection
    // ReSharper disable once ClassNeverInstantiated.Local
    private class DummyMessage : Message
    {
        public DummyMessage() : base(string.Empty) { }
    }
}

public class MessageProcessor<T> : MessageProcessor, IProcessor<T>
where T : Message
{
    public MessageProcessor() : base(typeof(T))
    {
    }

    public override ProcessResult Process(Message message)
    {
        var processor = FindProcessor(message) as MessageProcessor;
        if (processor == null)
        {
            var error = "Wasn't able to find a processor for the message";
            return Fail(message, new NotSupportedException(error));
        }

        try
        {
            message.Validate();
            Debug.Assert(processor != null, "processor != null");
            return processor.ProcessImpl(message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Fail(message, e);
        }
    }

    public virtual ProcessResult Process(T message)
    {
        var error = "Processor was found but there is no implementation for this message.";
        return Fail(message, new NotImplementedException(error));
    }

    internal override sealed ProcessResult ProcessImpl(Message message)
    {
        return Process(message.MapTo() as T);
    }

    protected ProcessResult Ok(Message message, object context = null)
    {
        return new ProcessResult()
            {
                Message = message,
                ProcessedBy = this,
                UpdatedObject = context
            };
    }

    private ProcessResult Fail(Message message, Exception error)
    {
        return new ProcessResult()
            {
                Message = message,
                ProcessedBy = this,
                Error = error
            };
    }
}
```

Utilities

```
public static class ParseUtils
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _parsers =
        new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>()
        {
            { typeof(int), (Func<string, int?>)ParseInt },
            { typeof(decimal), (Func<string, decimal?>)ParseDecimal },
            { typeof(double), (Func<string, double?>)ParseDouble },
            { typeof(float), (Func<string, float?>)ParseFloat },
            { typeof(DateTime), (Func<string, DateTime?>)ParseDateTime },
            { typeof(Guid), (Func<string, Guid?>)ParseGuid }
        };

    public static int? ParseInt(this string value)
    {
        int v;
        if (int.TryParse(value, out v))
        {
            return v;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static float? ParseFloat(this string value)
    {
        float v;
        if (float.TryParse(value, out v))
        {
            return v;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static double? ParseDouble(this string value)
    {
        double v;
        if (double.TryParse(value, out v))
        {
            return v;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static decimal? ParseDecimal(this string value)
    {
        decimal v;
        if (decimal.TryParse(value, out v))
        {
            return v;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static DateTime? ParseDateTime(this string value)
    {
        DateTime v;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out v))
        {
            return v;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Guid? ParseGuid(this string value)
    {
        Guid v;
        if (Guid.TryParse(value, out v))
        {
            return v;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Guid? ParseBool(this string value)
    {
        Guid v;
        if (Guid.TryParse(value, out v))
        {
            return v;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static object ConvertToType(this string value, Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(string))
        {
            return value;
        }
        if (_parsers.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            var converted = _parsers[type].DynamicInvoke(value);
            if (converted != null)
            {
                return converted;
            }
        }
        if (type.GetTypeInfo().IsEnum)
        {
            return Enum.ToObject(type, ParseInt(value));
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static class ReflectionUtils
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetSubclassesOfType<T>(params object[] constructorArgs)
    {
        var types = typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Select(type => type.GetTypeInfo())
            .Where(type => !type.IsGenericType && type.IsClass 
                && !type.IsAbstract && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)))
            .Select(type => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type.AsType(), constructorArgs))
            .ToList();
        return types;
    }
}
```

---

For sake of completness a test method so you can see how you use this

```
private readonly IDispatcher _dispatcher = Dispatcher.Instance;
[TestMethod]
[DataRow(@"EC\RBHello World")]
public void CanDispatchEchoMessage(string sdmp)
{
    var result = _dispatcher.Dispatch(sdmp);
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.IsNull(result.Error);
    Assert.AreEqual(sdmp, result.Message.Raw);

    var strongTypedMessage = result.Message as EchoMessage;
    Assert.IsNotNull(strongTypedMessage);
    Assert.AreEqual("Hello World", strongTypedMessage.ReplyBack);

    Assert.AreEqual("Hello World", result.Message.Parameters["RB"]);
}
```

Also forgot `ProcessResult`

```
public class ProcessResult
{
    public object UpdatedObject { get; set; }

    public Exception Error { get; set; }

    public IProcessor ProcessedBy { get; set; }

    public Message Message { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (Error != null)
        {
            return $"Processor {ProcessedBy.Name} failed processing {Message.Raw}. {Error}";
        }
        return $"Processor {ProcessedBy.Name} processed {Message.Raw}";
    }
}
```

Sorry again it seems I forgot to include the dispatcher and parser

```
public sealed class Parser : IParser
{
    private static readonly Regex _regex =
        new Regex(@"(?<message>.{2})(\\(?<parameter>[^\\]{2,}))*", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public Message Parse(string message)
    {
        if (!_regex.IsMatch(message))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot parse " + message);
        }

        var groups = _regex.Match(message).Groups;

        return new Message(groups["message"].Value)
            {
                Raw = message,
                Parameters = groups["parameter"].Captures
                    .Cast<Capture>()
                    .ToDictionary(
                        c => c.Value.Substring(0, 2),
                        c => c.Value.Substring(2))
            };
    }
}

public class Dispatcher : IDispatcher
{
    public static readonly IDispatcher Instance =
        new Dispatcher(new Parser(), MessageProcessor.Instance);

    private readonly IParser _parser;
    private readonly IProcessor _processor;

    private Dispatcher(IParser parser, IProcessor processor)
    {
        _parser = parser;
        _processor = processor;
    }

    public ProcessResult Dispatch(string Message)
    {
        var message = _parser.Parse(Message);
        return _processor.Process(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just top down a few things that I noticed... assuming you can use C# 7.

> ```
> "(?<message>.{2})(\\(?<parameter>[^\\]{2,}))*"
> ```
>
> all messages contain 2 Letter message code **and a variable number of parameters, each parameter with a 2 letter identifier and an arbitrary value**.

By multiple parameters I guess you mean for example: `EC\RBHello\RBWorld`? Are you sure this wors like that? I'm asking because as far as I know for this to work the the inner group should be repeating but it's not and the outher group is optional so `EC` is a valid message here. Since you didn't post code parsing this I cannot comment on that. Maybe you use some workarounds for it.

---

> ```
> public Message MapTo()
> ```

There is something missing because reading this I automatically think `MapTo`*What*?

---

> ```
> public void Validate() { }
> ```

Not implemented?

---

> ```
> // ReSharper disable NonReadonlyMemberInGetHashCode
> ```

You can get rid of such comments if you make your properties `get` only.

---

> ```
> public override bool Equals(object obj)
> {
>     var other = obj as Message;
>     if (other == null)
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
>
>     return other.MessageCode == MessageCode;
> }
> ```

This could just be:

```
return obj is Message as m && Message == m.MessageCode;
```

---

> ```
> if (GetType() == typeof(MessageProcessor<DummyMessage>))
> ```

There should be a helper variable for this. It's not clear what you are checking here especially that a `DummyMessage` is used.

---

> ```
> protected IProcessor FindProcessor(Message message)
> {
>     if (!_processors.ContainsKey(message))
>     {
>         return null;
>     }
>     return _processors[message];
> }
> ```

It's not necessary to read the dictionary twice. You can use `TryGetValue`.

---

> ```
> public string Name
> {
>     get { return GetType().Name; }
> }
> ```

or just

```
public string Name => GetType().Name;
```

---

> ```
> // The class is instantiated via reflection
> // ReSharper disable once ClassNeverInstantiated.Local
> ```

Reshaper has an attribute for this. Just decorate the class with the [`UsedImplicitlyAttribute`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#UsedImplicitlyAttribute) that:

> Indicates that the marked symbol is used implicitly (e.g. via reflection, in external library), so this symbol will not be marked as unused (as well as by other usage inspections).

---

> ```
> public static int? ParseInt(this string value)
> ```

I find all these methods should be called like `ParseIntOrNull` so it's clear that they don't fail but return some *defaul* value similar to linq methods `ElementAtOrDefault` etc.

---

> ```
> public static int? ParseInt(this string value)
> {
>     int v;
>     if (int.TryParse(value, out v))
>     {
>         return v;
>     }
>     return null;
> }
> ```

You can make it a one liner:

```
return int.TryParse(value, out var x) ? x : (int?)null;
```

---

> ```
> GetSubclassesOfType
> ```

This should be called `CreateSublassesOfType` as this is what it does. It does not search for instances of the subclasses but it creates them.

Comment: By multiple parameters I meant multiple but different. IE `EC\RBHello\XPWorld` And yes. `EC` could be a valid message, depending on `Validate` implementation which is not defined yet.